# Is Carbon event handling still working in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, osx-elcapitan

Is Carbon event handling still working in OS X 10.11 El Capitan?

```
EventTypeSpec OPNEventType[3];
    OPNEventType[0].eventClass = getEventClass();
    OPNEventType[0].eventKind  = getEventKindInsert();
    OPNEventType[1].eventClass = getEventClass();
    OPNEventType[1].eventKind  = getEventKindRemove();
    OPNEventType[2].eventClass = getEventClass();
    OPNEventType[2].eventKind  = getEventKindDataAvailable();
    handlerUPP = NewEventHandlerUPP(CBOpticonHandler);

    //  create the OPN interface, which is passed to our event handler
    interface = CreateOPNInterface();

    OSStatus status = InstallApplicationEventHandler(handlerUPP, 3, OPNEventType, interface, NULL);
    if ( status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"%s: InstallApplicationEventHandler failed!", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        [self stop];
        return;
    }
```

This code seems not working anymore after upgrading OS X. What could be an alternative?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you get an error when installing the handler? If so, what error? Or is it that your handler is never called? What are the actual event class, kind pairs you're trying to handle? Are you sure those are occurring? Have you tried [event tracing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391-CH1-SECHLTBEVENTTRACE)?

Comment: @KenThomases The handler is never called. Event class: OPTI eventKind:1. It's a OPTICON OPN 2001 barcode scanner. I don't manage to trace the events because of some issues while running gdb (app signature I guess).

Comment: I suspect that this old scanner is no longer supported on El Capitan. But I would like to have proof of this.

Comment: You can use lldb rather than gdb. Also, if you scroll up just a bit from where I linked, there's a way to enable tracing of all Carbon events by setting an environment variable. That doesn't require any debugger, but the output is very verbose. All of that said, I suspect your scanner requires a driver which is not compatible with El Capitan.

Comment: IIRC you can't install non-Apple drivers in /System/Library/Extensions any more; they have to be in /Library/Extensions/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a .dylib or a .framework, that was supplied with the SDK? Try using .dylib - it doesn't crash and InstallApplicationEventHandler completes successfully.

However, the communication itself isn't working properly, i.e., the demo project, provided with the SDK isn't able to read/set time on the device, read barcodes (although the app detects when the scanner is connected/disconnected). I believe this has something to do with the change of the CDC driver in El Cap, as the scanner itself is a CDC device.

Just wondering - have you had any luck fixing that problem and making OPN2001 work on El Capitan?

Comment: No I didn't figure out how to fix it. But I found out that unplugging and plugging the scanner *after* opening the app solves the issue. This is the same with the OPN Scanner demo app provided by Opticon.

Comment: @Patrick for what it's worth, Opticon released an updated library, just in case anyone else faces this problem, you can download it on their website